# SQL Not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm still new to SQL.

I've got a query to count the number of students that attend a certain lecture and I've been trying to group the records by the lectureid so I don't have 10 records for the same lecture.

```
SELECT ATTENDANCESHEET.LECTUREID,TOPIC, (
       SELECT COUNT(STUDENTID) AS ATTENDANCE
           FROM ATTENDANCESHEET
           WHERE ATTENDANCESHEET.STUDENTID = LECTURE.STUDENTID
       )
FROM ATTENDANCESHEET,LECTURE
WHERE ATTENDANCESHEET.LECTUREID = LECTURE.LECTUREID
GROUP BY ATTENDANCESHEET.LECTUREID;
```

I'm getting the error "not a GROUP BY expression". Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help -- at least the columns in the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to solve the issue of `group by` without knowing the expected result

```
SELECT ATTENDANCESHEET.LECTUREID,TOPIC, (
       SELECT COUNT(STUDENTID) AS ATTENDANCE
           FROM ATTENDANCESHEET
           WHERE ATTENDANCESHEET.STUDENTID = LECTURE.STUDENTID
       )
FROM ATTENDANCESHEET,LECTURE
WHERE ATTENDANCESHEET.LECTUREID = LECTURE.LECTUREID
GROUP BY ATTENDANCESHEET.LECTUREID,TOPIC,LECTURE.STUDENTID;   -- added the topic and studentid from lecture table
```

but I think what he's trying to do  is

```
SELECT ATTENDANCESHEET.LECTUREID,TOPIC, count(LECTURE.STUDENTID) cntstudent
FROM ATTENDANCESHEET,LECTURE
WHERE ATTENDANCESHEET.LECTUREID = LECTURE.LECTUREID
GROUP BY ATTENDANCESHEET.LECTUREID,TOPIC
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you have a correlated query.  The correlation clause (the `where` in the subquery) is using a column from the outer query that is not aggregated.  In addition, you have a column `topic` that is not in the `group by`.

I believe the query you want is more simply written as:

```
select a.lectureid, count(*) as attendance
from attendancesheet a
group by a.lectureid;
```

I notice that you have `topic` in the `select`.  That is also an issue.  Perhaps you want:

```
select l.lectureid, l.topic, count(*) as attendance
from attendancesheet a join
     lecture l
     on a.lectureid = l.lectureid
group by l.lectureid;
```

Or, if you have `studentid` in `lecture`, perhaps:

```
select l.lectureid, l.topic, count(*) as attendance
from lecture l
group by l.lectureid;
```

EDIT:

The data structure doesn't make sense to me, but perhaps you need both keys for the `join`:

```
select l.lectureid, l.topic, count(*) as attendance
from attendancesheet a join
     lecture l
     on a.lectureid = l.lectureid and a.studentid = l.lectureid
group by l.lectureid;
```

Comment: That didn't work.My table "Lecture" as lectureid as the primary key and studentid as a foreign key. Then, I have another table called "attendancesheet" with a composite key (lectureid + studentid). I'm trying to count the number of students and also display the topic of the lecture (column in the lecture table)

Comment: @PedroPinheiro . . . That makes no sense.  What does `lecture` represent?  I would expect one row per "class", not one per "student".  In any case, aggregating `attendancesheet` by lecture would seem to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding TOPIC to the group by :)